# NullReferenceException while using List

Tags: c#, list, listbox, nullreferenceexception

I want to refresh the listbox, but I get this NullReference and I don't want to create an Animal and add it to the list. Can you guys please help me?

```
public void UpdateForm()
{
    if (administration.Animals != null)
    {
        List<string> reservedAnimals = new List<string>();
        List<string> notReservedAnimals = new List<string>();

        lbReserved.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Animal a in administration.Animals)
        {
            if (a.IsReserved == true)
            {
                reservedAnimals.Add(a.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is the `NullReferenceException` occurring on?

Comment: The if (administration.Animals != null) line

Comment: Then whatever object `administration` is, is `null`.  You should add a check to ensure the object is not `null` as so: `if (administration != null && administration.Animals != null)`.

Answer (score 0):

`administration` is `null` - that's way you receive exception in this line. You should initiate somewhere `administration`, e.g.:

```
administration = new YourType();
```

It's difficult to write more, because you gave not enough code.

Comment: Just debug code and you will see wheter it's null. Maybe you initiate it somewhere, but call `UpdateForm` before?

Answer (score 0):

administration is not initialized or is null.

Proof whether it is null before using it:

```
if (administration == null)
    {
        administration = new TypeOfAdministration();
    }
```

So your code should look like this:

```
public void UpdateForm()
{
    if (administration == null)
    {
        administration = new TypeOfAdministration();
    }

    if (administration.Animals != null)
    {
        List<string> reservedAnimals = new List<string>();
        List<string> notReservedAnimals = new List<string>();

        lbReserved.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Animal a in administration.Animals)
        {
            if (a.IsReserved == true)
            {
                reservedAnimals.Add(a.ToString());
            }
        }
    }    
}
```